# Elements and their properties in a finite field

Tags: number-theory

I need help proving the following.

> If $\alpha \in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]/\langle f\rangle$ for some irreducible $f\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$ of degree $n$, then both $\alpha+\alpha^{p}+\alpha^{p^2}+\cdots+\alpha^{p^{n-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha\alpha^{p}\alpha^{p^2}\cdots\alpha^{p^{n-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

I can show it for specific cases of $p$ and $n$, but I don't even know where to start in proving it generally.

Answer (score 2):

Show that both the sum and the product satisfy $x^p=x$. Use $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$, a property that holds in characteristic $p$ thanks to the binomial theorem, and the fact that every unit in a finite field with $p^n$ elements must be a $p^n-1$ root of unity, hence $x^{p^n}=x$ holds for all $x$ here.

Every element of ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$, a total of $p$ elements, satisfies $x^p=x$ as well. Given that this is a field, is it possible for any more than $p$ elements to satisfy it?

More generally, since the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^p$ permutes $\{\alpha,\alpha^p,\cdots,\alpha^{p^{n-1}}\}$, *any* symmetric polynomial $f$ in $n$ variables evaluated at $\alpha,\alpha^p,\cdots,\alpha^{p^n}$ yields a value in ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$.

Comment: +1 Very nice. The very first phrase already is worth an upvote.